# "Boot mgr is missing" error shown during boots up

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, multi-boot, bootmgr

Initially I had Windows XP, after some time in another partition I installed Windows 7. Dual boot is working well for me but after some time I removed the windows XP. After that When I tried to boot up only having Windows 7 I got an error **Boot mgr is missing**.

I don't understand why this error is shown during booting because my Win 7 is working well when I had dual boot.

Comment: The reason you cannot boot your system is because you deleted the boot manager.  You can fix this by using the repair console.

Comment: can't you specify it little elaborately. How can I get the repair console by inserting windows cd or anything else?

Answer (score -2):

Your issue here is the fact that your boot manager has been sitting on the old partition (Windows 7 replaced the XP boot manager, but it put it where the old one has been).

[Suggested copying the boot manager which obviously won't work between partitions.]

As an alternative, just boot from the Windows 7 DVD and use the automatic repair option. It should be able to find Windows 7 as well as be able to determine the boot manager being missing.

Comment: This answer is incomplete.  The user is using the same HDD.  He installed Windows 7 to another partition on the same HDD.  So your advice to reconnect the old drive makes no sense.  Besides he cannot even get to the disk management console, because he is unable to boot his computer, based on the described problem.

Comment: Yes I think only last part is correct.

Comment: Ah you're right. Missed that part (or simply expected another physical drive. Editing... As for the console, I expected him to be able to restore the old state booting up as usual.